# Textual representation of a C++ function

Tags: haskell, formatting

I need to create an instance of `Show` of a somewhat complicated type that represents a C++ function. The "serialization" gives me a Haskell interpretation of the said function.

It works as I wish but it looks utterly horrible, with the string concatenations, point-free conversions and nested let bindings.  How could I improve readability of the code?

```
instance Show Function where
    show (Function templateArgs returnT fname fArgs) =
        let toLowerIfPolymorphic argName =
               let lcArg = strToLower argName in
                    if lcArg `elem` (map snd templateArgs)
                    then lcArg
                    else id argName in
        concat [
            fname, " :: (",
            intercalate ", " (
                filter (/="") . map (
                \(concept, tIdent) ->
                    if not $ elem concept ["Any", "typename", "class"]
                    then concept ++ " " ++ strToLower tIdent
                    else ""
                ) $ templateArgs    
            ), ") => ",
            intercalate " -> " (
                map toLowerIfPolymorphic . map (show . fst) $ fArgs
            ),
            (if not $ null fArgs then " -> " else ""),
            toLowerIfPolymorphic . show $ returnT
        ]
```

The `Function` is:

```
data Function = Function {
                    funcTemplateArgs :: [(Concept, Identifier)],
                    funcReturnT      :: CppType,
                    funcName         :: String,
                    funcArgs         :: [(CppType, Identifier)]
                }
```

`CppType` is basically a sum-type representing `Scalar` and `Parameterzied` types. Just synonyms for tuples. `Concept` / `Identifier` is a `String` synonym. Everything is an instance of `Show`.

Also I find the `if condition then f else id` very strange. "Do nothing if false" is somewhat silly.

Answer (score 1):

I would clean this up by bringing what you can to the top level (hiding it using a module export list if need be) as new functions. There are also some sectioning/alias changes that I think would make it more readable.

```
toLowerIfPolymorphic :: [(Concept, Identifier)] -> Identifier -> Identifier
toLowerIfPolymorphic templateArgs argName
    | lcArg `elem` (snd $ unzip templateArgs) = lcArg
    | otherwise                               = argName
  where
    lcArg = strToLower argName
```

I often prefer guards to `if _ then _ else _`, it helps cut down on word soup (and I still don't understand why we don't have `boolCase :: Bool -> a -> a -> a` in the `Prelude`). Consider how `snd . unzip` more specifically captures your intent than using a more powerful but generic higher-order function like `map`.

The bit with `["Any", "typename", "class"]` should work out better with some reordering. Instead of applying a partial transformation with a sentinel value (i.e. `filter (not . null)` with occasional `""` values), drop the junk and then transform the good stuff.

```
showConstraints :: [(Concept, Identifier)] -> [String]
showConstraints templateArgs = map display . filter valid $ templateArgs
  where
    display (concept, ident) = concept ++ " " ++ strToLower ident
    valid (concept, _) = concept `notElem` ["Any", "typename", "class"]
```

Then your `Show` instance ends up looking something like this.

```
instance Show Function where
  show (Function templateArgs returnT fName fArgs)
     = fName
    ++ " :: ("
    ++ intercalate ", " (showConstraints templateArgs)
    ++ ") => "
    ++ intercalate " -> " (map (toLowerIfPolymorphic templateArgs . show . fst) $ fArgs)
    ++ (if null fArgs then "" else " -> ")
    ++ toLowerIfPolymorphic templateArgs (show returnT)
```

I'd probably take this one step further though to handle not having any constraints (in which case you don't want `"() =>"` to show up, presumably) and write one more helper function.

```
wrap :: String -> String -> String -> String
wrap _     ""      _   = ""
wrap start content end = start ++ content ++ end
```

Giving—

```
instance Show Function where
  show (Function templateArgs returnT fName fArgs)
      =  fName
      ++ " :: "
      ++ wrap "(" (intercalate ", "   $ showConstraints templateArgs)       ") => "
      ++ wrap ""  (intercalate " -> " $ map (lowerPoly . show . fst) fArgs) " -> "
      ++ lowerPoly (show returnT)
    where
      lowerPoly = toLowerIfPolymorphic templateArgs
```